# Google Analytics: prevent sending page title

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How can I prevent GA from tracking the page title? Setting `_setDetectTitle` to `false` still sends the page title in the request to GA server (`utmdt`). Due to privacy issues, I do not want the page title to leave the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_setDetectTitle` is working just fine for me. You just need to call it before the `_trackPageview` call:

```
    var _gaq=_gaq||[];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDetectTitle', false]);    
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'])
```

You can contrast the __utm.gif hit sent in a [version with _setDetectTitle set to false](http://jsfiddle.net/ED8DE/), versus [sent in a standard version](http://jsfiddle.net/y7rWG/).

In the former, the `utmdt` isn't set, in the latter, it is.

Screenshots: The one on the left sends the page title; the one on the right doesn't.

[image: Sends the page title]
[image: Doesn't send the page title]

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine when I try it. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDetectTitle', false]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In GA4, it is possible to configure [event modifications](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872) from the dashboard. An example of an event is `page_view` which has parameters such as `page_title` and `page_referrer`. It is possible to specify that a parameter should be changed or even removed<sup>1</sup>. **Modifications are calculated client side (before data is sent to Analytics)**.

#### To setup event modification:

- Go to admin section and locate the data stream that you want to modify
- Click on modify events
- Setup a modification as shown in the screenshot<sup>1</sup>

[image: Locate the stream in Google Analytics admin]
[image: Modify events section]
[image: Event modification instructions]

#### Data collection, before and after:

[image: Google Analytics beacon - before - with page title]
[image: Google Analytics beacon - after - page title redacted]

---

<sup>1</sup> Removing a parameter did not work for me, however it should work according to the documentation.